# Elastic Beanstalk Ruby processes consuming CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have had a Rails 3 app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk for close to 2 years now.  For the most part, I haven't had any issues; however, I recently upgraded to one of their new Ruby configurations (64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running Ruby 2.1 (Passenger Standalone)) and I've been fighting an issue for several days where one of more Ruby processes will consume the CPU - to the point where my site becomes unresponsive.  I was using a single m3.medium instance, but I've since moved to a m3.large, which only buys me some time to manually log into the EC2 instance and kill the run away process(es).  I would say this happens once or twice a day.

The only thing I had an issue with when moving to the new Ruby config was that I had to add the following to my .ebextensions folder so Nokogiri could install (w/bundle install)...

```
commands:
  build_nokogiri:
    command: "bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries"
```

I don't think this would cause these hanging processes, but I could be wrong.  I also don't want to rule out something unrelated to the Elastic Beanstalk upgrade, but I can't thing of any other significant change that would cause this problem. I realize this isn't a whole lot of information, but has anyone experienced anything similar to this?  Anyone have suggestions for tracing these processes to their root cause?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my run away Ruby process issue by SSHing into my EC2 instance and installing/running gdb.  Here's a link - http://isotope11.com/blog/getting-a-ruby-backtrace-from-gnu-debugger with the steps I followed.  I did have to sudo yum install gdb before.

gdb uncovered an infinite loop in a section of my code that was looping through days in a date range.

Answer (score 0):

Since you upgraded your beanstalk configuration, I guess you also upgraded Ruby/Rails version. This bumped up all gem versions. The performance issue probably originate from one of these changes (and not the Hardware change).
So this brings us into the domain of RoR performance troubleshooting:
1. Check the beanstalk logs for errors. If you're lucky you'll find a configuration issue this way. give it an hour.
2. Assuming all well there, try to setup the exact same version on your localhost (passenger + ruby 2.1 + gems version). If you're lucky, you will witness the same slowness and be able to debug.
3. If you'd like to shoot straight for production debugging, I suggest you'd install newrelic (or any other application monitoring tool) and then drill into the details of the slowness in their dashboard. I found it extremely useful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Tal.  I found this article this morning - http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/04/29/debugging-stuck-ruby-processes-what-to-do-before-you-kill-9/.  Next time I SSH in and see the hanging process(es), I'm going to give gdb a try.